# Create a feature branch and keep it up to date with mainline

Tags: git, github, command, repository

Goal: Create a feature branch for our team for a new feature on our project. Our current branch that we merge code into is mainline. We need a feature branch, feature-redesign, to be an offshoot of mainline where we can safely merge changes without affecting other code.

Questions:

1. How can i do this - what commands do i use?
2. How do i keep my feature-redesign branch up to date with mainline?
3. Any best practices for large-scale projects or naming recommendations?

Notes: I have read quite a few SO questions on this, but not finding what i think is the above scenario. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is *my* personal take on how to work on a separate branch while also merging stuff from mainline.

Assumptions: this is a closed team that will be working on this, you are *in sync* when big things will happen. Read on.

Start your branch and start putting stuff in there...... when the moment come to get things in from mainline, one person will do this with everybody knowing that this is taking place *and* they won't be committing into the branch until this is finished. We know that they have separate unpublished branches based on this branch while they develop the stuff that will be merged into the team branch later.

First, create a temporary branch to keep the *old* tip of the branch.... people will need it later to rebase their work.

```
git checkout the-team-branch
git pull # get latest stuff from the remote
git branch temporary
git push some-remote temporary
```

Now, it is *rebasing* time (yeah, yeah.... put your hands on your head, *rebase-haters*.... the world *of successful branching* is out there waiting for the braves of soul to conquer it by rebasing their feature branches every time a commit is merged in the mainline branch!!!).

```
git rebase --rebase-merges some-remote/the-mainline-branch # add more options at will
```

This rebase should be a very simple process with no hiccups.... oh, sorry, it's not April 1st: expect this to be **living hell**.... hundreds of conflicts.... on multiple commits when rebasing.... if you are brave enough and are able to finish the rebase, now you have updated your branch with mainline changes.... and it's time to put the result in the remote:

```
git push -f
```

Send out the mail telling your team that work is finished and that they should be able to move over their branches from the old branch to the new one like this:

```
git fetch some-remote
git rebase some-remote/temporary some-random-branch --onto some-remote/the-team-branch # rebase once per feature branch
```

After they have rebased all of their branches (the ones they are using for this team development, of course), you should be able to move forward with development just like nothing happened.... actually, **did anything happen?**

Oh, and remove the temporary branch after you have all rebased their branches.

Well... that's just *one* of your questions.... hope it helps, either if choosing to rebase or by convincing you to merge instead (my heart is with rebasing but I know it comes with challenges and consequences).

PS there might be micro-scenarios like.... how can I ask another developer to help me in the middle of the rebase with a conflicting revision I am not sure how to get in? I think that is *in itself* a good question for the site.... and which I do not know that has been asked before (it could, for sure.... and the answers will be interesting... I even came up with a way to theoretically *cope* with it just now).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to run this by the team and see what they think! Will upvote / add question in here once i run through it. Thank you!!